# Show $x^{\alpha}\sin(1/x^{\alpha})$ is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$-Hölder

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I found several similar questions but none has been answered. So I'd like to post again.

Fix $\alpha > 0$. Let $f_{\alpha}(x)=x^{\alpha}\sin(1/x^{\alpha})$ when $x > 0$; and $f_{\alpha}(0) = 0$.

How can I show that $f_{\alpha}$ is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$-Hölder on $[0,1]$?

In other words, I need to show that,

$$\exists C, \forall x,y\in[0,1], |f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}}$$

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You have to show, that there is a $C>0$ with $|f_{\alpha}(x) |\cdot |x|^{-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}}\leq C$ for $x$ in a small neighborhood of zero.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This might inspire you? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/511713/1104384

Comment: @Jochen, the problem with Holder inequality is not when one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$. The worse situation is when $1/x^{\alpha} = 2\pi k + \pi/2$ and $1/y^{\alpha} = 2\pi k - \pi/2$. For large integer $k$ this gives that the constant $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1}$  can't be improved

Comment: @PavelGubkin ah ok, thank you. +1

Answer (score 2):

The following inequalities give the proof of the statement for $\alpha = 1$. If $x$ or $y$ is zero then the required inequality is trivial otherwise we can assume that $x\ge y > 0$ then
$$
\left|x^{\alpha}\sin(1/x^{\alpha}) - y^{\alpha}\sin(1/y^{\alpha})\right|\le \left|\sin(1/x^{\alpha})(x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha})\right| + \left|y^{\alpha}(\sin(1/x^{\alpha}) - \sin(1/y^{\alpha}))\right|
\\
\le \left|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}\right| + 2y^{\alpha}\left|\sin\left(\frac{x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}}{2x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}\right)\right|,
$$
where las t inequality follows from the
$$
|\sin a - \sin b| =|2\sin\left((a - b)/2\right)\cos((a + b)/2)|\le 2\sin\left((a - b)/2\right)|.
$$
Next, we can bound
$$
\left|\sin\left(\frac{x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}}{2x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}\right)\right|\le \min\left(1, \frac{x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}}{2x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}\right)\le \sqrt{\frac{x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}}{2x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
|f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\alpha}(y)|\le \left|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}\right| + 2y^{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}}{2x^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}}}\le\left|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}\right| + C\sqrt{\left|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}\right|}, 
$$
which is exactly the $1/2$-Holder inequality for $\alpha = 1$. Probably the similar argument can give a proof for a general case, however I can't come up with the needed corrections right now.