A Gaokao (College Entrance Exam in China) question with regard to the function $f(x)=x\ln{x}$.
The question is described as follows: $f(x)=x\ln{x}$.

Find the tangent line of the curve $y=f(x)$ at $(1,f(1))$.
Given that $\forall x\in (0,+\infty):\;f(x)\geq a(x-\sqrt{x})$, find the value of $a$.
Prove that $\forall x_1,x_2\in (0,1):\;\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\rvert\leq \sqrt{\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert}$.

(1) and (2) are effortless, while (3) is a conundrum for me. Due to a dramatic trend to disjoint and ease the math curriculum, editors have well before deleted limits and integrals from our textbooks. We have to take the derivative formulas of several simple functions as axioms and those are essentially the tools for us to solve problems. In consequence, the suggested answer is grotesquely lengthy and tedious. I was wondering if there would be someone ingenious and obliging enough to give an incisive answer and save my racked brains.
My idea (plain and unfruitful): Set $g(x)=(f(x)-f(a))^2-x+a,\;0<a\leq x<1$. I  have to prove $g(x)\leq 0$. I take notice that $g(a)=0$, so the question would be easy if $g(x)$ is decreasing over $[a,1)$. However, $g''(x)=2[(1+\ln{x})^2+\ln{x}-\frac{f(a)}{x}]$, which probably necessitates discussing cases as the suggested answer does.

Hint: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(t)dt |\le \sqrt {|x_1-x_2|}\sqrt {\int_0^{1}(f'(t))^{2}dt}$ make  a change of variable for the last integral.

See  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/511713/42969 for the general approach how to show that a function is Hölder continuous.

If you know the inequality $\ln u \le u - 1, \forall u > 0$, here is an approach (hint): WLOG, assume that $x_1 < x_2$. We have
$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|
= |x_1\ln x_1 - x_2 \ln x_2|
= \left|x_1 \ln \frac{x_2}{x_1} - (x_2 - x_1)\ln \frac{1}{x_2} \right|.$

By the way, I think it holds that $|x_1\ln x_1 - x_2\ln x_2| \le 2\mathrm{e}^{-1} \sqrt{|x_1

x_2|}$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in (0, 1)$. Here $2\mathrm{e}^{-1}$ is the best constant.


For all $0<x_2\leq x_1<1$, it's clear that $x_1-x_2\leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$ and $\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2}\leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$. Therefore $-(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2})\leq x_1\ln{x_1}-x_2\ln{x_2}\leq x_1-x_2 \Rightarrow | x_1\ln{x_1}-x_2\ln{x_2} | \leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$.
Set $g(x)=x\ln{x}-x$ and $h(x)=x\ln{x}+\sqrt{x}$, for both of which $x\in (0,1)$.
$g'(x)=\ln{x}<0$. $h'(x)=1+\ln{x}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, $h''(x)=x^{-\frac{3}{2}}(x^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{4})$. $h'(\frac{1}{16})=3-4\ln{2}>0$. Thus $g(x)$ is decreasing and $h(x)$ is increasing on the interval $(0,1)$, which implies that for all $0<x_2\leq x_1<1$ we have $-(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2})\leq x_1\ln{x_1}-x_2\ln{x_2}\leq x_1-x_2$, hence $\rvert x_1\ln{x_1}-x_2\ln{x_2} \lvert \leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$ and the proof is complete.
The hints above refer to Hölder's inequality, which is conceivably the direct source of this problem, but it is not covered on China's high school syllabus. Here the answer makes use of two inequalities $x_1-x_2\leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$ and $\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2}\leq \sqrt{x_1-x_2}$ which render it slightly tricky. The answer here is not really short but is far more readable than the suggested one.
The suggested answer:



Alternative solution.
In this answer, we need to know the inequality $$\ln u \le u - 1, \forall u > 0. \tag{1}$$
WLOG, assume that $x_1 < x_2$. We have
$$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|
= |x_1\ln x_1 - x_2 \ln x_2| 
= \left|x_1 \ln \frac{x_2}{x_1} - (x_2 - x_1)\ln \frac{1}{x_2} \right|. \tag{2}$$
Using (1), we have
$$x_1 \ln \frac{x_2}{x_1}
\le x_1 (x_2/ x_1 - 1) = x_2 - x_1 
\le \sqrt{x_2 - x_1}.$$
Using (1) and $4(y - 1) \le y^2$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align*}
 (x_2 - x_1)\ln \frac{1}{x_2} &= (x_2 - x_1)\cdot 4\ln \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x_2}}\\
 &\le (x_2 - x_1) \cdot 4\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x_2}} - 1\right)\\
 &\le (x_2 - x_1)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}\\
 &\le (x_2 - x_1)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2 - x_1}}\\
 &= \sqrt{x_2 - x_1}.
\end{align*}
(Note: Actually we use $\ln\frac{1}{x_2} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}} $ equivalently.)
Thus, we have
$$\left|x_1 \ln \frac{x_2}{x_1} - (x_2 - x_1)\ln \frac{1}{x_2} \right|
\le \sqrt{x_2 - x_1}.$$
We are done.
